# How can I copy names of files selected in explorer to the clipboard? (Like SendToX)

Tags: windows

In Win95 and XP, I used SendToX (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751394.aspx) to select a number of files in directory and copy the names to the clipboard so that I could paste them into a document or my notes.

For example, I just burned a DVD of a couple dozen EXE files and I want to print a table of contents of what's on the DVD by including the exact filename of each file on the DVD.
With SendToX, I could select the files send to clipboard, paste them into a notepad window and print them, and it was done.

Is there a way to do this in Win7?

I did some searching and the tool at
  http://www.gabrieleponti.com/software/#sendtotoys
looks pretty nice, but I'd like to use a tool provided by Microsoft if possible.

Does anyone know of a tool provided by Microsoft to copy a selection of files to the clipboard?

Answer (score 7):

On Vista and Windows 7, you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Right Click</kbd> and you'll see a new entry *Copy Path*. This copies the full path of all of the files you have selected to the clipboard.

This is exactly what I wanted.

I got this information from the [Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaapps/thread/8bdc3e3e-9be8-42da-b964-91ab2db7d704)